# What's the difference between BAREWORD and *BAREWORD in Perl?

Tags: perl

```
my $childpid = open3(HIS_IN, HIS_OUT, HIS_ERR, $cmd, @args);

my $childpid = open3(*HIS_IN, *HIS_OUT, *HIS_ERR, $cmd, @args);
```

It seems the above both works for my application.

What's the difference between `BAREWORD` and `*BAREWORD` in Perl?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The meaning of a bareword varies. Most of the time, a bareword is a function call.

```
sub foo { say "Hello"; }
foo;
```

Sometimes, it's a string literal.

```
$x{foo}    # $x{"foo"}
```

In yet other circumstances, it produces a typeglob.

```
print STDOUT "foo";   # print { *STDOUT } "foo";
```

In this case,

```
open3(HIS_IN, HIS_OUT, HIS_ERR, ...)
```

is equivalent to

```
open3("HIS_IN", "HIS_OUT", "HIS_ERR", ...)
```

but `open3` uses that string as the name of a glob in the caller's package, so the above is functionally equivalent to

```
open3(*HIS_IN, *IS_OUT, *HIS_ERR, ...)
```

Comment: Is it also the case for open,close etc?

Comment: @new_perl, Due to special parsing rules, `open` and `close` cause the argument to be interpreted as a glob (directly), not as a string that's then used to fetch a glob. That's why `open(FOO, ...)` works under `use strict;` and `open3(FOO, ...)` doesn't.

Comment: @new_perl, I just said `open(FOO, ...)` means `open(*FOO, ...)`, so I imagine so.

Comment: I just tried,`open3(FOO, ...)` also works under `use strict;`, so I think this can't be used to judge whether it's interpreted as glob or string,what do you think?

Comment: @new_perl, Either your `strict` is broken (not likely!), you have a function named `FOO` (in which case `FOO` is a function call), or you are mistaken.

Comment: Do you mean `Symbol::qualify`(this is what converts bareword to glob) won't work if `use strict;` is on?

Comment: No, barewords as string literals aren't allowed under strict. `Bareword "FOO" not allowed while "strict subs" in use`. Strict off: `open3(FOO, ...)` is `open3("FOO", ...)`. Strict on: `open3(FOO, ...)` is an error.

Comment: Re "barewords as string literals aren't allowed under strict", ...except when auto-quoted by `=>`, a hash index, or `->`.